# Jasperstarter Usage

Tags: java, php, jdbc, jasper-reports, jasperstarter

I am trying to utilize Jasperstarter with MSSQL on Windows with a JDBC driver.  It seems never to find or connect with this driver for some reason despite using the same Driver and URL used by iReport which does work.  I can execute reports that do not access the DB, but once I add the database parameters the call fails.  I do not get any info back from the call, not sure where the debug stuff goes.  Are there any special path settings that need to be made to get this to work?  The exec call output just returns a 1 without any failure info.

PHP exec command stream:

> `"C:\\Inetpub\\wwwroot\\TekEnterpriseServer\\protected\\JasperPHP/JasperStarter/bin/jasperstarter pr ./reports/maintenance.jasper -f pdf -t generic --db-driver net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver --db-url jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/tekenterprise"`

Answer (score 0):

The jdbc driver must be put into the `jdbc` directory of the JasperStarter installation or the path to the driver jar must be specified with `--jdbc-dir`.

You have to specify username and password as part of the `--db-url`, see

http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat

You can get verbose output with:

```
jasperstarter -v pr ./reports/maintenance.jasper ...
```